# Converting ASCII number to it's ASCII character code - C(Not printing!)

Tags: c, file, int, character, ascii

I got some `Ascii` values read from a file in `C` using `fgetc()` method.
It converts the numbers to their Ascii number like: the value 4 equals to 52 because 52 is it's Ascii code and so on with all the integers.

Now all the answers about this use `pritf("%c",c)` to simply convert the 52 to 4 But I want to store the value 4 in an integer variable.

SomeCode:

```
int writeFileToArray(FILE* file, int* a, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    char temp;
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < length)
        {
            *(a + i) = fgetc(file);
            i++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Instead of getting 52,53,54 etc to the array i want to get 4,5,6 etc.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fairly straightforward when dealing with ASCII encoding. Simply subtract 48 from the ASCII value to convert to the number represented.

```
int actualNumber = asciiValue - 48;
```

Depending on how reliable your input data is, it's usually wise to range check that the input is actually in the range '0' to '9'. You can get some pretty strange results down the road if you blindly apply that formula to ASCII values that don't represent numbers.

Comment: you can even subtract char `'0'` instead of 48 to avoid magic consts

Comment: Yeah. after posting the question i got to it myself. Thanks man.

Comment: @Lashane Using `'0'` does not always work in corner cases yet is certainly practically with most coding.  OP wants to convert an _ASCII_ character to a  numeric value.  `'0'` is the value of the character 0 in the source code encoding which might not be ASCII.  So if code needs to port to a now rare EBCDIC machine or might port to a new fantasy platform, using something like `#define ASCII_0 48  int actualNumber = asciiValue - ASCII_0;` makes sense.

Comment: @chux agree, define is better